# React Hooks & React-Redux connect: What is the best practice to make them work together?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I would like to ask to the community what is the best practice to combine existing code using react-redux `connect()` and dependency management in hooks like `useEffect()`.

Let's look at the following example:

```
/* ... */

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: getTodos(state),
  currentUserId: getCurrentUserId(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({dispatch})

const mapMergeProps = (stateProps, {dispatch}, ownProps) => {
  return {
    ...stateProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...ownProps,
    fetchTodos: () => dispatch(fetchTodos(stateProps.currentUserId))
  }
}

const TodosListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mapMergeProps)

const TodosList = ({todos, fetchTodos, ...props}) => {

  const _fetchTodos = useCallback(fetchTodos, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    _fetchTodos()
  }, [_fetchTodos])

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos && todos.map((todo) => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

In the code above useEffect has all the dependencies, and useCallback ensures that useEffect is triggered only once.

It seems however like an extra layer of boilerplate: Without useCallback, the functions passed down as props that are coming from connect's `mapMergeToProps` will be recreated on every change of state, and will trigger `useEffect`.

My question is whether the code above is correct, and there's a better way to handle useEffect in the context described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change it to the following

```
// Leave this one like it is
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: getTodos(state),
  currentUserId: getCurrentUserId(state)
})

// Map the fetchTodos here
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchTodos,
}

// Completely remove the mergeProps
const TodosListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

// Then use the hook like this
const TodosList = ({ todos, fetchTodos, currentUserId, ...props }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos(currentUserId)
  }, [fetchTodos, currentUserId])

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos && todos.map((todo) => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

This will not trigger `useEffect` on each render because the props stay the same. It removes (some of the) boilerplate code. I also think it makes it easier to understand what is going and it will run the effect when the `currentUserId` changes, which is probably what is meant to happen.

Comment: I understand what you propose, and makes sense. The only caveat I see is that `mergeProps`, out of the box, does not play well with Hooks.

Comment: After some experimenting, I'll mark this one as valid. Not messing too much with mapMergeProps is probably the best course of action.